# Using a string as name to set property values

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have these big huge repetitive chunks of code in my project I am attempting to shrink them down. Take this piece example:

```
self.Day11.delegate = (id)self;
self.Day12.delegate = (id)self;
self.Day13.delegate = (id)self;
self.Day14.delegate = (id)self;
self.Day15.delegate = (id)self;
self.Day16.delegate = (id)self;
self.Day17.delegate = (id)self;
self.Day18.delegate = (id)self;
self.Day19.delegate = (id)self;
```

What I would like to do is make it that I can use a for loop or something similar to shrink it down like this:

```
   for (int i = 1 ; i<=9; i++) {
    NSString *var = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Day1%d",i];

    self.var.delegate = (id)self;

}
```

I know this doesn't work is there a possible way to do something like this?

Comment: It sounds like you need an array. Also, those casts to `(id)` are superfluous and *horrible.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, no, no.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *arrayOfDays;
```

Now get rid of all those day objects and fill that `self.arrayOfDays` with whatever all those individual day objects are...

Then...

```
for(int i=0; i<[self.arrayOfDays count]; ++i) {
    [[self.arrayOfDays objectAtIndex:i] setDelegate: self];
}
```

Or even better, if all those objects are of the same type (I'll assume they're of type `Day`), we can do:

```
for(Day *day in self.arrayOfDays) {
    day.delegate = self;
}
```

Best (per Daij-Dan's comment):

```
[self.arrayOfDays setValue:self forKeyPath:@"delegate"];
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! Sorry for bad code I am new to objective-c.

Comment: Wait, using the second way I get the yellow flag `assigning to 'id uitextfielddelegate ' from incompatible type *const __strong'`

Comment: 1 line only :: setValue:forKeyPath: `[self.arrayOfDays setValue:self forKeyPath:@"delegate"];`