# How to access the property of own class with its name as a string

Tags: objective-c, properties

I am looking for a way to access one of my property from its name.
  For example, I have 3 properties in a particular class as

```
 @property (nonatomic, weak) UIImageView *image1;  
 @property (nonatomic, weak) UIImageView *image2;  
 @property (nonatomic, weak) UIImageView *image3;
```

And I have a method as

```
 - (void)accessProperty:(NSString *)propertyName{
 //image1, image2 or image3 will be passed here.
 //how can I access the property with its name ?????
 }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Let me mention my need more precisely.
  I have 3 `imageView` but I want to set image to the particular imageView who's name matches with the name I passed to the method.  For example if I will call the method as
    `[self accessProperty:@"image1"];` Then it should set image to `imageView1` only

Comment: I believe properties are having `IBOutlet` otherwise `weak` object will be release after initialisation. To access your property with name use `[self valueForKey:propertyName]` KVC it will return whole object.

Comment: [Access ObjC property dynamically using the name of the property](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1969897) does tell you how you can do this, but [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210228/using-a-string-as-name-to-set-property-values?lq=1) gives you more important information: _why you shouldn't_ and what to do instead. See also: [Create multiple numbered variables based on a int](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2231783)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `valueForKey`.  This is [Key-Value coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) (KVC):

```
for (NSUInteger i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%u", i];
    UIImageView *value = [self valueForKey:key];
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Roohul The principle is the same; the type of `value` changes from `NSString` to `UIImageView` is all.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked fine.